# Change committer in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: android, git, github, intellij-idea

I want to change the committer (not the author) in IntelliJ Idea because when I do a commit I specify the author but later in GitHub it appears with the committer, and I want that both things be the same.

Images with description:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGFtP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/81KvV.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA uses your Git settings for who you are as the committer, although it does allow you to specific a separate author when making a commit. If your git settings are wrong, you need to set them [per the GitHub help section](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/#setting-up-git):

```
git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"
git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"
```

For most "normal" work, you should just set the Git settings, and leave the "Author" field in the commit dialog blank. Per the [IntelliJ IDEA Commit Changes dialog documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/commit-changes-dialog.html#d1487485e366), it's "useful when you are committing changes made by another person." It should just be blank if you're committing your own changes.